# How do I write Java brackets "[ ]" in Kotlin?

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin

I apologize in advance for my programming political incorrectness, as I do not know what the thing I need to type is called.

I have this Java code.

```
FrutasVerduras frutasVerduras_datos[] = new FrutasVerduras[] {

}
```

How would this be written in Kotlin?

Comment: It's called an [array](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#arrays).

Comment: @shmosel Not so fast.  Taken in another context, it could also be an empty regex character class :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That thing is called an [array](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#arrays). Currently, in Kotlin you can't create them using the same syntax as in Java. Though that's [going to change](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2017/06/early-access-program-for-kotlin-1-2-has-been-started) (see "Language feature: array literals in annotations") a little in the near future. The Kotlin way to do it is using [`arrayOf(...)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/array-of.html). Keep in mind though that for basic types you should use the adequate function (e.g. for `Int` use `intArrayOf`) as otherwise the JVM will create an array of `Integer`s (object) instead of `int` (primitive) causing 12 (?) bytes more per *element*

Comment: I've typed this:
    `var frutasVerduras_datos: FrutasVerduras = arrayOf(FrutasVerduras) { };`

But I get the errors
1. Please specify constructor invocation; classifier 'FrutasVerduras' does not have a companion object.
2. Passing value as a vararg is only allowed inside a parenthesized argument list.

Comment: @StealthDroid Remove the `{ };` part. If `FrutasVerduras` is a class, not an instance, also add `()` after `FrutasVs`

Comment: I put parentheses here:
`var frutasVerduras_datos: FrutasVerduras = arrayOf(FrutasVerduras());`,
here: `var frutasVerduras_datos: FrutasVerduras() = arrayOf(FrutasVerduras);`
and here `var frutasVerduras_datos: FrutasVerduras() = arrayOf(FrutasVerduras());`, but still to no avail. I receive the same error.

Comment: `var frutasVerduras_datos: Array<FrutasVerduras> = arrayOf(FrutasVerduras())`

Comment: I don't think they will introduce array literals generally in Kotlin. The suggestion has been quite controversial in the community. It only works in annotations for 1.2.